# Sampling without replacement using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a lot of text files that look like this:

```
>ALGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>BLGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>HLGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>DLGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>ELGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>FLGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>JGGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>POGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
```

Is there a way to do a sampling without replacement using awk?

For example, I have this 8 lines, and I only want to sample 4 of these randomly in a new file, without replacement. 
The output should look something like this:

```
>FLGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>POGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT    
>ALGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
>BLGKAHOLAGGATACCATAGATGGCACGCCCT
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with resampling?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant just "sampling without replacement". Going to edit that. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "sampling without replacement"?

Comment: What would an example output look like, and why?

Comment: Umm... then what do you mean by "sampling"? Do you want to remove duplicate lines from the files? Do you want to remove duplicates in each file or across all files?

Comment: "Sampling without replacement" here means that a single line can be selected only once, since it is not returned to the pool of possible choices after each selection. Contrast with "with replacement", where any line that is replaced (i.e., put back) in the pool of choices, so it might be selected multiple times.

Comment: Strikes me as easiest to do with perl, skipping random numbers of lines as you go through the file, then re-ordering randomly after the fact, if you need them out-of-order.

Answer (score 14):

How about this for a random sampling of 10% of your lines?

```
awk 'rand()>0.9' yourfile1 yourfile2 anotherfile
```

I am not sure what you mean by "replacement"... there is no replacement occurring here, just random selection.

Basically, it looks at each line of each file precisely once and generates a random number on the interval 0 to 1. If the random number is greater than 0.9, the line is output. So basically it is rolling a 10 sided dice for each line and only printing it if the dice comes up as 10. No chance of a line being printed twice - unless it occurs twice in your files, of course.

For added randomness (!) you can add an `srand()` at the start as suggested by @klashxx

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()} rand()>0.9' yourfile(s)
```

Comment: Nice solution ,I would add a call to srand in order to "get random numbers that are truly unpredictable." awk 'BEGIN{srand()}rand() > 0.9'

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but I wouldn't. I would use `shuf` or `sort -R` (neither POSIX) to randomize the file and then select the first `n` lines using `head`.

If you really want to use `awk` for this, you would need to use the `rand` function, as Mark Setchell points out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `shuf`, but `sort -R` will create a file object as large as the original (either on disk, or in memory if piping through) which could be problematic for large files.

Comment: @cmh I'm sure `shuf` would do the same. But while OP said he had several files, he didn't say they were large.

Comment: @kojiro, Sure, it was just a footnote for anyone in the future considering this approach with a large file.

Comment: There's no need to `head -n 4 | shuf`, you can just use `shuf -n 4`

Answer (score 1):

To obtain random samples from a text file, without replacement, means that once a line has been randomly selected (sampled) it cannot be selected again.  Thus, if 10 lines of 100 are to be selected, the ten random line numbers need to be unique.

Here is a script to produce `NUM` random (without replacement) samples from a text `FILE`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# random-samples.sh NUM FILE
# extract NUM random (without replacement) lines from FILE

num=$(( 10#${1:?'Missing sample size'} ))
file="${2:?'Missing file to sample'}"

lines=`wc -l <$file`   # max num of lines in the file

# get_sample MAX
#
# get a random number between 1 .. max
# (see the bash man page on RANDOM

get_sample() {
  local max="$1"
  local rand=$(( ((max * RANDOM) / 32767) + 1 ))
  echo "$rand"
}

# select_line LINE FILE
#
# select line LINE from FILE

select_line() {
  head -n $1 $2 | tail -1
}

declare -A samples     # keep track of samples

for ((i=1; i<=num; i++)) ; do
  sample=
  while [[ -z "$sample" ]]; do
    sample=`get_sample $lines`               # get a new sample
    if [[ -n "${samples[$sample]}" ]]; then  # already used?
      sample=                                # yes, go again
    else
      (( samples[$sample]=1 ))               # new sample, track it
    fi
  done
  line=`select_line $sample $file`           # fetch the sampled line
  printf "%2d: %s\n" $i "$line"
done
exit
```

Here is the output of a few invocations:

```
./random-samples.sh 10 poetry-samples.txt
 1: 11. Because I could not stop for death/He kindly stopped for me 2,360,000 Emily Dickinson
 2: 25. Hope springs eternal in the human breast 1,080,000 Alexander Pope
 3: 43. The moving finger writes; and, having writ,/Moves on571,000 Edward Fitzgerald
 4: 5. And miles to go before I sleep 5,350,000 Robert Frost
 5: 6. Not with a bang but a whimper 5,280,000 T.S. Eliot
 6: 40. In Xanadu did Kubla Khan 594,000 Coleridge
 7: 41. The quality of mercy is not strained 589,000 Shakespeare
 8: 7. Tread softly because you tread on my dreams 4,860,000 W.B. Yeats
 9: 42. They also serve who only stand and wait 584,000 Milton
10: 48. If you can keep your head when all about you 447,000Kipling

./random-samples.sh 10 poetry-samples.txt
 1: 38. Shall I compare thee to a summers day 638,000 Shakespeare
 2: 34. Busy old fool, unruly sun 675,000 John Donne
 3: 14. Candy/Is dandy/But liquor/Is quicker 2,150,000 Ogden Nash
 4: 45. We few, we happy few, we band of brothers 521,000Shakespeare
 5: 9. Look on my works, ye mighty, and despair 3,080,000 Shelley
 6: 11. Because I could not stop for death/He kindly stopped for me 2,360,000 Emily Dickinson
 7: 46. If music be the food of love, play on 507,000 Shakespeare
 8: 44. What is this life if, full of care,/We have no time to stand and stare 528,000 W.H. Davies
 9: 35. Do not go gentle into that good night 665,000 Dylan Thomas
10: 15. But at my back I always hear 2,010,000 Marvell

./random-samples.sh 10 poetry-samples.txt
 1: 26. I think that I shall never see/A poem lovely as a tree. 1,080,000 Joyce Kilmer
 2: 32. Human kind/Cannot bear very much reality 891,000 T.S. Eliot
 3: 14. Candy/Is dandy/But liquor/Is quicker 2,150,000 Ogden Nash
 4: 13. My mistress’ eyes are nothing like the sun 2,230,000Shakespeare
 5: 42. They also serve who only stand and wait 584,000 Milton
 6: 24. When in disgrace with fortune and men's eyes 1,100,000Shakespeare
 7: 21. A narrow fellow in the grass 1,310,000 Emily Dickinson
 8: 9. Look on my works, ye mighty, and despair 3,080,000 Shelley
 9: 10. Tis better to have loved and lost/Than never to have loved at all 2,400,000 Tennyson
10: 31. O Romeo, Romeo; wherefore art thou Romeo 912,000Shakespeare
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to sample the file using a fixed schema, like sampling one record each 10 lines.  You can do that using this `awk` one-liner:

```
awk '0==NR%10' filename
```

If you want to sample a percentage of the total, then you can program a way to calculate the number of rows the `awk` one-liner should use so the number of records printed matches that quantity/percentage.

I hope this helps!

Comment: No, your opening statement is incorrect if you do it the way I said. Basically, it looks at each line of each file precisely once and generates a random number on the interval 0 to 1. If the random number is greater than 0.9, the line is output. So basically it is rolling a 10 sided dice for each line and only printing them if the dice comes up as 10. No chance of a line being printed twice.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Oh, I understand.  Thanks for the clarification.  I have edited my answer so there's no misunderstandings.  However, as random is random (D'Oh!), it could be the case that all of them (that is, the whole file) gets printed... or the case that none of them gets printed...  That is why I was giving an idea that didn't depend on randomness, but on the number of records you wanted to output.