# Reading N percent of lines from CSV file and writing to another file

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file with about 5000 rows of data. I want to read about 10% of the data(say, 50 rows).

for example:
lets say that i have a csv file with 1000 rows of data. what i need to do is take a percentage of the data( say 10% i.e., 10 lines) and put it into another csv file without making use of dataframes i.e, without putting the data into memory, directly put it into the second csv file. Hope this tells u what i need.

Comment: Use nrows - Number of rows of file to read. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: lets say that i have a csv file with 1000 rows of data. what i need to do is take a percentage of the data( say 10% i.e., 10 lines) and put it into another csv file without making use of dataframes i.e, without putting the data into memory, directly put it into the second csv file. Hope this tells u what i need.

Comment: You seem confused about a couple of things... 10% of 5,000 is 500. And, you cannot read any file without opening it. Opening is not reading - it is just preparing to read. Opening a file does not load that file into memory - only a `read()`-like operation reads a file.

Comment: i didnt know that, thanks for your help  then, bud.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't code it in `python`, but the principle is as you read each line of the CSV, generate a random number between [1..100], and if it is greater than 90, write the line to your output file.

This approach has the benefit of only needing to load a single line into memory at a time.

I did it in `awk` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35158432/2836621).

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell how many rows there are in your file without reading it first. Well, you can, only if you know your filesize and all your rows are of fixed length, which is rather doubtful with diverse data. If, on the other hand, you know how many rows there are in your file ahead of time, you could simply open two files, one for reading and another for writing and read-write the necessary rows in a for loop one by one. You don't need pandas for this at all, e.g:

```
linecount = 10
with open('1.csv', 'r') as f, open('out.csv', 'w') as o:        
    while linecount > 0:
        o.write(f.readline())
        linecount -= 1
```

Comment: The only problem is, when u are opening the files, u are putting the file contents into the memory. i'm not allowed to do that. I have do directly transfer the file contents to another without opening the files

Comment: is there a way to do that?

Comment: You are not reading the whole file into memory right away. Your OS uses file caches as necessary, you can tweak this process via kernel settings in Linux, for example, but you can't get rid of memory usage completely. Any program that reads from disk and then writes to disk is using some kind of memory buffer for this task. I am afraid that you can't do this without using memory or opening a file.

Comment: Thanks bud for all your help