# How to randomly sample lines from a large text file - from the command line

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I am working with a ~0.5 GB text file, and I want to extract a representative subset of lines. Say, one millionth of them. I've create a small script to do this:

```
import random
result = []
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if random.random() < 0.000001:
            result.append(line)
```

But it would be more useful for my purpose if I could do this from the command line, without a script. Note, I don't care how many lines out output, I just want to be able to set a percent/probability of outputting each line.

MY QUESTION/REQUEST: Is how to do this with just a short one-liner which is suitable for the commandline.

Comment: Simpe `awk`-based solution... http://stackoverflow.com/a/22303906/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is perl ok? Try this:

```
cat yourfile.txt | perl -ne 'print if (rand() < 0.000001)'
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`.  `perl -ne 'print if rand() < 0.000001' < yourfile.txt`.

Comment: I displayed it using cat assuming the original poster wanted to use this in a string of pipes, e.g. cat | ... |  sort | ... and so on. Also, it's often helpful to start with a cat because that puts the filename on the left side.