# Random down-sampling of a big file

Tags: python, performance, io, bioinformatics, coding-efficiency

I have a very big textual file **(~500MB) containing ~100M rows.**
What I want to accomplish is to **randomly sample (approximately) 5M rows** out of the file as fast as possible, into a new file.

The result is flexible - is has to be a "good enough" randomness, and not a perfect one, and the number of sampled rows can be very close to 5M but does not have to be exact.

I do have one advantage here, that the file contains **similar length rows** making it easier to estimate the number of rows in the file using the size of the first row.

My major target here is run-time efficiency since I have to perform this process over many thousands of similar files.

I've examined many methods of getting this done, from creating random sorted row indices and then running over the file, to [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Since the number of sampled rows is very high (5M), sorting pre-calculated random indices is too expensive, and also running over the collected samples is reservoir sampling is highly expensive.

I thought about scanning the file in **random "jumps"** to create a linear but random sweep of the file.
But I'm still not sure what's the best way to get this done in a way that the randomness of the sample will be as even as possible.

**Can I make this code better in terms of run-time efficiency and even sampling?**

```
def random_sample_file(f_name, f_target, num_sampled_rows):

    def _estimated_row_size(f):
        return len(f.readline())

    def _take_step():
        return random.randint(row_size, max_leap)

    file_size = os.path.getsize(f_name)

    with open(f_name, 'rb') as f_in, open(f_target, 'w') as f_out:

        row_size = _estimated_row_size(f_in)
        max_leap = file_size / num_sampled_rows

        for i in xrange(num_sampled_rows):
            _step = _take_step()
            f_in.seek(_step, 1)
            _next_new_line = f_in.readline()   # getting to the next new line (in case the pointer landed in the middle of a line)
            f_out.write(f_in.readline())

    return os.path.getsize(f_target)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22303906/2836621

Comment: I suggest you have a look at how the `-s` option of `samtools view` is implemented, to select o proportion of the records: https://github.com/samtools/samtools/blob/develop/sam_view.c#L286 If I remember well, the technique fits your requirements. It is based on hashing the content of each line and then computing a number between 0 and 1 based on this hash, which is compared with the desired proportion of records to retain.

Comment: Thanks Bil! I'll check it out